# Is $f'(0)$ is exists or not?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Problem taken from walter rudin Books

> Let $f$ be a continuous real function on $ℝ^1$, of which it is known
> that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x ≠ 0$ and that $f'(x) → 3$ as $x → 0$.
> Does it follow that $f'(0)$ exists?

## My attempt : I think  NO

i take $$f(x) = \left\{ \matrix{
  3\sin x\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x \ne 0 \hfill \cr 
  1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

then $\lim_{ x\rightarrow 0} f'(x)=3$ exist But $f'(0)$  doesnot exist  because at  $x= 0 $ $ f$ is not contnious

Is is it true ?

Comment: Rudin's question is about continuous functions and your function is not continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is not continuous, the answer is yes. By the mean value theorem, there exists $c_x\in]0,x[$ such that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f’(c_x)$$
Letting $x\rightarrow 0$ gives you that $f’(0)$ exists and that $f’(0)=3$.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion is to use the mean value theorem:

$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(\xi)$
for $\xi$ between $0$ and $h$. Then pass to the limit